# Haskell error message Expecting one more argument

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

Im trying to solve this kind of equatin: e^x + sqrt(x) = d, when d is known.  It does not have analytic solution so I use variation of binary search to solve it:

```
helper x = exp x + sqrt x

ex2 c0 c1 x 
| abs (h0 - h1) < 10 ^^ (-6) = c0
| hm < x = ex2 m c1 x
| hm >= x = ex2 c0 m x
where h0 = helper c0
  h1 = helper c1
  m = c0 + (c1 - c0)/2
  hm = helper m
```

This works fine from ghci (c0 and c1 is min and max value for search) but i have problems reading argument x from stdio:

```
main = do
 seed <- getLine
 let output = show ex2 0 6 (read seed :: Floating) -- Result is somewhere between helper(0) and helper(6)
     in putStrLn output
```

This breaks my code. It does not compile or load in ghci. I got this error message:

ex2.hs:14:46:
    Expecting one more argument to ‘Floating’
    Expected a type, but ‘Floating’ has kind ‘* -> Constraint’
    In an expression type signature: Floating
    In the fourth argument of ‘show’, namely ‘(read seed :: Floating)’
    In the expression: show ex2 0 6 (read seed :: Floating)

Can someone explain what it means and how to fix my main function?

Comment: `Floating` is a type class, see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#t:Floating
So the compiler is correct, you need to specify what instance of the type class you want.

Comment: I tried also changing "Floating" to "Float" or "Double" but then I got much more errors.

Comment: Change `Floating` to `Float` or `Double`, and change `in putStrLn output` to just `putStrLn output`, aligning it to the same indentation level as the `let`.

Comment: Another error: `show (ex2 ... (read seed :: Double))` requires parentheses.

Comment: chi: Thank you very much.  Code was otherwise ok but i missed  those parenheses. Now it works! Thx!

Answer (score 1):

There was parentheses missing in let.. line:

Another error: show (ex2 ... (read seed :: Double)) requires parentheses. –  chi